# Gnome doesn't want start

Tags: debian, boot, gnome

my problem is following:
some time I just restarted my computer, after restart the gnome doesn't want to show up, I have only the 6 tty's terminals ( I can log in and do whatever I want ).
I am struggling from yesterday why is that when I type:

```
service gdm3 status

gdm3.service - LSB: GNOME Display Manager
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/gdm3)
Active: active(exited) since Fri 2015-01-09 13:57:38 CET; 2s ago
Process: 995 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/gdm3 start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

It is written in the status "active(exited)" I don't know if its good or bad.
My distribution is Debian jessie (testing), but I have tried to downgrade it to wheezy ( I though that maybe some recent update of jessie caused the problem), but after downgrading the problem still exists. Stack Overflow right now the state of my Debian is wheezy (stable).
Please for help because I can't move on alone.
Show me some instruction because I got stuck and don't even know where to look for the problem.

I just found something out:
I logged in as root and started /etc/X11/Xsession script by hand 
It produced the following to /root/.xsession-errors:

```
xrdb: Can't open display ''
xhost: unable to open display ""
openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
cannot connect to brltty at: 0
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Window manager error: Unable to open X display
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand where you're having a problem. Do you see the login screen ? Is it the terminal one or the graphic one ? Can you login ?

Comment: You're not giving any system information. Try to show: inxi -b Also, current stable is stretch, jesse is old stable now. You almost certainly have an issue with your video driver.  Also, show: cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | tail -n 20 which will show why your graphic environment failed to start.

Answer (score -1):

To me, it looks like your system is having trouble detecting your display, thus causing it to run in low graphics mode.
**FIRST,** `sudo rm /home/$USER/.config/monitors.xml` *Afterwards, reboot your system.*
**Afterwards, if that did not work,** attempt to reconfigure xserver and xorg. You can do this by `sudo dpkg-reconfigure xorg* && sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver*`  *Afterwards, restart your display manager.*

Comment: I'd recommend making backup of monitors.xml _just in case_. You never want to remove some configs without leaving a way to get them back.

Comment: This is bad advice, you don't do this until you know what's wrong, this is the exact wrong procedure to follow. It's probably just an nvidia driver or something that isn't loading correctly, or the old fglrx, but that can't be known until we see the system data: inxi -b